# LibGDX Box2D Body and Sprite AND DebugRenderer out of sync

Tags: 2d, java, physics, box2d, libgdx

I am having a couple issues with Box2D bodies.  I have a GameObject holding a Sprite and Body.  I use a ShapeRenderer to draw an outline of the Body's and Sprite's bounding boxes.  I also added a Box2DDebugRenderer to make sure everything's lining up properly.

My problem is the Sprite and Body at first overlap perfectly, but as I turn the Body moves a bit off the sprite then comes back when the Car is facing either North or South.

Here's an image of what I mean: (Not sure what that line is, first time to show up)
BLUE is the Body, RED is the Sprite, PURPLE is the Box2DDebugRenderer.

[image]

[image]

Also, you probably noticed a purple square in the top right corner.  Well that's the Car drawn by the Box2D Debug Renderer.  I thought it might be the camera but I've been playing with the Cameras for hours and nothing seems to work.  All give me weird results.

Here's my code:

**Screen:**

```
public void show() {
        // --------------------- SETUP ALL THE CAMERA STUFF ------------------------------ //
    battleStage = new Stage( 720, 480, false );

    // Setup the camera. In Box2D we operate on a meter scale, pixels won't do it. So we use
        // an Orthographic camera with a Viewport of 24 meters in width and 16 meters in height.
    battleStage.setCamera( new OrthographicCamera( CAM_METER_WIDTH, CAM_METER_HEIGHT ) );
    battleStage.getCamera().position.set( CAM_METER_WIDTH / 2, CAM_METER_HEIGHT / 2, 0 );


    // The Box2D Debug Renderer will handle rendering all physics objects for debugging
    debugger = new Box2DDebugRenderer( true, true, true, true );
    //debugCam = new OrthographicCamera( CAM_METER_WIDTH, CAM_METER_HEIGHT );
}

public void render(float delta) {

    // Update the Physics World, use 1/45 for something around 45 Frames/Second for mobile devices
    physicsWorld.step( 1/45.0f, 8, 3 );     // 1/45 for devices 

    // Set the Camera matrices and clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    battleStage.getCamera().update();

    // Draw game objects here
    battleStage.act(delta);
    battleStage.draw();

    // Again update the Camera matrices and call the debug renderer
    debugCam.update();
    debugger.render( physicsWorld, debugCam.combined);

    // Vehicle handles its own interaction with the HUD

    // update all Actors movements in the game Stage
    hudStage.act( delta );      
    // Draw each Actor onto the Scene at their new positions
    hudStage.draw();
}
```

**Car: (extends Actor)**

```
public Car( Texture texture, float posX, float posY, World world ) {

    super( "Car" ); 

    mSprite = new Sprite( texture );
    mSprite.setSize( WIDTH * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO, HEIGHT * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO );

    mSprite.setOrigin( mSprite.getWidth()/2, mSprite.getHeight()/2);    // set the origin to be at the center of the body

    mSprite.setPosition( posX * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO, posY * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO );    // place the car in the center of the game map

    FixtureDef carFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

    mBody = Physics.createBoxBody( BodyType.DynamicBody, carFixtureDef, mSprite );
}

public void draw() {
    mSprite.setPosition( mBody.getPosition().x * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO, mBody.getPosition().y * Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO );
    mSprite.setRotation( MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * mBody.getAngle() );
    // draw the sprite
    mSprite.draw( batch );
}
```

**Physics: (Create the Body)**

```
public static Body createBoxBody( final BodyType pBodyType, final FixtureDef pFixtureDef, Sprite pSprite ) {

    float pRotation = 0;
    float pWidth = pSprite.getWidth();
    float pHeight = pSprite.getHeight();

    final BodyDef boxBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    boxBodyDef.type = pBodyType;

    boxBodyDef.position.x = pSprite.getX() / Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO;
    boxBodyDef.position.y = pSprite.getY() / Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO;

    // Temporary Box shape of the Body
    final PolygonShape boxPoly = new PolygonShape();
    final float halfWidth = pWidth * 0.5f / Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO;
    final float halfHeight = pHeight * 0.5f / Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO;
    boxPoly.setAsBox( halfWidth, halfHeight );  // set the anchor point to be the center of the sprite

    pFixtureDef.shape = boxPoly;        

    final Body boxBody = BattleScreen.getPhysicsWorld().createBody(boxBodyDef);
    boxBody.createFixture(pFixtureDef);

}
```

Sorry for all the code and long description but it's hard to pin down what exactly might be causing the problem.

Comment: It seems that you are using different cameras for each object. You're using debugCam for the debugrenderer and battleStage.getCamera() for sprites. Try using the same camera, probably this will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem. The problem is caused by you convert a body position by a Consts.PIXEL_METER_RATIO, but you do not convert a render camera to handle the conversion.

Solution:

debugCam.scale(Consts.METER_PIXEL_RATIO, Consts.METER_PIXEL_RATIO, 0);
debugger.render(physicsWorld, debugCam);